# AdView inside RelativeLayout which is going off screen

Tags: android

My AdView is placed at the bottom of RelativeLayout, but my RelativeLayout is going off screen, making my AdView not visible. How do I fix that?

Edit: This XML contains collapsing toolbar layout.

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    ...
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/category_swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview_category_details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post you XML file please?

Comment: @AngeloParente Added

Comment: I have added an answer. See if it helps. It's a code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that.

You should use a `RelativeLayout` as parent layout, put the adview at the bottom of it, and specify `android:layout_above="@+id/adView"` property, This is a sample code:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/adView">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/main_button_background">

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

           <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/category_swipe_refresh_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_category_details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

delete `adview` from your layout and put them both in another `RelativeLayout` and set attribute `android:above="@id/adview"` for the inner `RelativeLayout`

Comment: That's not working. I've added my xml in the post now.